# How handle singletop navigation in Jetpack Compose with screen with arguments

Tags: android, android-jetpack-navigation

I have a scenario with three screens. First the main screen A. Lastly two screens with parameters: screen B("screenB?arguments={arguments}}") and screen C("screenC?arguments={arguments}").

The flow in the android app can be:

- A -> B -> C ->

*Before* = **A -> B -> C** -> Pressing back on **C** | *After* = **A**

- A -> B1 -> C1 -> B2 -> C2

*Before* = **A -> B1-> C1 -> B2** -> pressing back on B2 | *After* = **A**

*Before* = **A -> B1 -> C1 -> B2 -> C2** -> pressing back on C2 | *After* = **A->B2**

- A -> B1 -> B2 -> B3 -> B4 (screen B can open itself with different parameters, in this case B1, B2, B3 should be `popBackStack()`)

*Before* = **A->B1->B2->B3->B4** -> pressing back on b4 | *After* = **A**

I can add a work-around but I was wondering if Jetpack Compose Navigation provides a solution for that. I could not find any sample or description in the documentation. Most of the samples I found have no arguments for the path.

Edit:

When pressing back from B screen we are popping back to A screen.

When pressing back from C screen we are popping back to B screen.

User should not be able to see old versions of B and C screen, they should behave like SingleTop, even though they have different arguments.

Comment: Can you format this in terms of Before [A -> B] and After [A -> B -> C] kind of calls? It isn't clear what you want your back stack to be before and after a specific transition in your app

Comment: Thanks, I have edited. The main issue is being singleTop with different arguments and that B screen needs to always return to the A screen.